# Defining steps in C# Selenium project for Allure report

Tags: c#, selenium, allure, nunit-3.0

I am wondering is it possible to define allure steps for tests in C# just like in Java. Is there any way to use it?

```java
@Step("Step title: {0}")
public void func(String parameter, WebDriver driver) {}
```

Comment: Did you look in the docs? What does it say there?

Comment: Yep. I checked it and it has manual only for Java. Author says: All features are supported by Java test frameworks, so we only provide Java examples here. For details on how a particular adapter works with the test framework of your choice, refer to the adapter guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've found an answer

```cs
        public Page DoAction(Object object)
        {
            AllureLifecycle.Instance.WrapInStep(() =>
            {
                pageInput.SendKeys(object.field);
            }, "Action");
            return new HomePage();
        }
```